# How to convert a date from a Datepicker to Mysql DATETIME format using java?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, web

I have a date (05/15/2013) which is from a HTML Datepicker. I want to save this value in a mySQL column, which is the type of `DATETIME`. Format should be `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

[STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
STR_TO_DATE(string, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

You can specify the format as per your requirement

Comment: you can use that one before using query

Answer (score 0):

You could use joda time with date formatters like this:

```
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse("05/15/2013", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("mm/dd/yyyy"));
    String result = dateTime.toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-mm-dd"));
```

Comment: You don't need to use external librares in such simple cases.

Comment: Ok, sure, let's use the broken and non-thread-safe `java.util.Date` just so we don't have to add another include to our project...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` class, e.g.

```
String pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date today = new Date();
String output = formatter.format(today);
```

You can find more on official [Oracle tutorial page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Remember that SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411944/java-text-simpledateformat-not-thread-safe

Comment: I don't get the point of your comment. It's not a parallel code.

Comment: Am I dreaming? This is bunch of method-scope code. If you make it non-thread safe I'll give you Nobel price for creativity. Thanks for "-1", if it's yours please re-learn java.

Comment: A DateFormat rarely stays for very long as a method variable, usually ending up as a field and that's where the thread-safety becomes an issue.

Comment: Dear @vikingsteve, please write to Oracle, because you found serious bug in their OFFICIAL tutorial: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
String new_date_string = your_date_string.replace("/", "-");
System.out.println(str);
```

or you can use regex

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(new_date_string);
```