# Does ThreadLocal need to be used here?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

I m wondering when do we need to use the threadlocal variable?, I have a code that runs multiple threads, each one read some files on S3, I wish to keep track of how many lines read out of the files altogether, here is my code:

```
final AtomicInteger logLineCounter = new AtomicInteger(0); 
for(File f : files) {
   calls.add(_exec.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
       readNWrite(f, logLineCounter);
       return null;
    }
    }));
}
for (Future<Void> f : calls) {
   try {
      f.get();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      //
   }
}
LOGGER.info("Total number of lines: " + logLineCounter);
...

private void readNWrite(File f, AtomicInteger counter) {
    Iterator<Activity> it = _dataReader.read(file);

    int lineCnt = 0;
    if (it != null && it.hasNext()) {
       while(it.hasNext()) {
         lineCnt++;
         // write to temp file here

       }
       counter.getAndAdd(lineCnt);
    }
}
```

my question is do I need to make the `lineCnt` in the `readNWrite()` method to be threadlocal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to use ThreadLocal here - your code looks perfectly fine:

- `lineCnt` is a local variable which is therefore not shared across thread => it is thread safe
- `counter.getAndAdd(lineCnt);` is an atomic and thread safe operation

If you are interested, there are several posts on SO about the use of ThreadLocal, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817856/when-and-how-should-i-use-a-threadlocal-variable).

Answer (score 2):

`lineCnt` is already "thread local" since it's on the stack.  Use `ThreadLocal` only when you need thread-local copies of instance member variables.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to make lineCnt a `ThreadLocal` explicitly. `lineCnt` is a local variable to the thread. It is not accessible by any other thread.

You can get  more information about ThreadLocal [here](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2010/11/java-thread-local-how-to-use-and-code-sample/)

ThreadLocal from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

> These variables differ from their normal counterparts in that each
>   thread that accesses one (via its get or set method) has its own,
>   independently initialized copy of the variable. ThreadLocal instances
>   are typically private static fields in classes that wish to associate
>   state with a thread

Answer (score 1):

**-** A `Thread` has a `Stack`, `Register`, and `Program Counter`.

**-** `lineCnt` is already into the `ThreadLocal`.

**-** `lineCnt` is a **personal copy** of the instance variable lineCnt **for this thread**, and its **not visible** to any other thread .