# How do you cache data only for the duration of the http request using apache shiro in a servlet container?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, shiro

More specifically, I find that I'm implementing a custom `AuthorizingRealm`, which declares template methods `doGetAuthenticationInfo()` and `doGetAuthorizationInfo()` for returning `AuthenticationInfo` and `AuthorizationInfo` objects, respectively.

However, when I retrieve the data for the AuthenticationInfo (a JPA entity) in doGetAuthenticationInfo(), I find that I already have the necessary AuthorizationInfo. Alas, there's no apparantly good way to hang onto this data, so I have to throw it out only to perform another JPA lookup when the authorization filter ultimately gets its turn in the filter chain.

Behold:

```
public class CustomRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

  @Override
  protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) {
    UsernamePasswordToken userPassToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;
    String username = userPassToken.getUsername()

    User user; // Contains username, password, and roles
    // Perform JPA lookup by username...
    return constructSimpleAuthenticationInfoFromUser(user);
  }

  @Override
  protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
    // Look up user again? :(
    ...
  }
}
```

I've considered a number of possibilities:

1. **Use realm caching**. The application will run in a distributed environment so there could be any arbitrary number of JVMs running. The default realm cache manager implementations don't solve all of the inherent problems and setting up an enterprise implementations seems out of scope for this project.
2. **Use the subject's session**. There is no server-side state and I'd like to keep it that way if possible. Perhaps you can force the session to behave like request scope, but I wouldn't know how to do so and that risks being obfuscated.
3. **Implement my own Subject**. There appears to typically be one Subject instance per request, but it's unclear how to bootstrap this and I would risk losing a lot of potential functionality.
4. **Use the Shiro ThreadContext object**. I could attach the data to the ThreadContext as a threadlocal property. Servlet containers generally follow a thread-per-request model, and the Subject instance itself seems to chill out here, awaiting its inevitable garbage collection. Shiro also appears to build up and tear down the context automatically. However, there's not much documentation on this and the source code is hard for me to follow.

Finally, the default WebSecurityManager keeps singleton instances of the CustomRealm around, one per JVM it seems. Simply setting some local instance property is not thread-safe.

This seems like a common data retrieval option and a typical deployment scenario. So, what am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with option 4 - Using `ThreadLocal` object as your requirement clearly says that the object lifetime must be of http request.

Have a look at this discussion: [When and how should I use a ThreadLocal variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817856/when-and-how-should-i-use-a-threadlocal-variable)

ThreadLocal doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html