# What is the Use and need of thread local

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

I was exploring the Thread local in Java. I could not understand as why do we need this class. I can achieve the same motive if I just simply pass a new object to each thread for execution as same thing happens if i use initialValue(). I simply return a new object for each thread in initialvalue().

But say i have two threads, ThreadOne: A and ThreadTwo B. Now I want them to have a copy of own of say SimpleDateFormat class. I can do this by warping the object of SimpleDateFormat in a ThreadLocal Class and then using initialValue() I can return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmm");. Same motive I can achieve by creating two new Objects of SimpleDateFormat and p[assing one each to ThreadOne : A. and ThreadTwo : B. How does ThreadLocal help me extra

Regards,

Comment: Some nice answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817856/when-and-how-should-i-use-a-threadlocal-variable

Comment: +1 for question.  In some 30 years of writing multithreaded apps, I have never seen a convincing argument for thread-local vars, not have I ever felt any need to use them.  If I need a 'thread local' something, then it goes in as a member of the thread class - all the member functions have access to it, one 'something' per thread, job done.

Comment: thanks for the +1 :) . But still I think I need to explore more ont he subject to get a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 6):

There are some nice examples already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817856/when-and-how-should-i-use-a-threadlocal-variable) for your question.

But I try to explain the 2nd part:

> *But say i have two threads, ThreadOne: A and ThreadTwo B. Now I want
>   them to have a copy of own of say SimpleDateFormat class. I can do
>   this by warping the object of SimpleDateFormat in a ThreadLocal Class
>   and then using initialValue() I can return new
>   SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmm");. Same motive I can achieve by
>   creating two new Objects of SimpleDateFormat and p[assing one each to
>   ThreadOne : A. and ThreadTwo : B. How does ThreadLocal help me extra*

Often, you need to format dates with a certain format, and it's ofcourse a good idea to create the `SimpleDateFormat` object once (instead of creating a new `SimpleDateFormat` for every time that you need to format a date).

So you might have something like this:

```
public class DateUtils {  
    private final static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");  

    public String formatDate(Date date) {  
        return dateFormat.format(date);  
    }  
}
```

This is going to fail if multiple threads call `formatDate(...)` at the same time (you might get strange output or `exceptions`) because `SimpleDateFormat` is not `Thread-Safe`. To make it thread-safe, you can use `ThreadLocal`:

```
public class DateUtils {  
    private final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> dateFormat = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>() {  
        @Override  
        protected DateFormat initialValue() {  
            return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");  
        }  
    };  

    public String formatDate(Date date) {  
        return dateFormat.get().format(date);  
    }  
}
```

Now every thread (or call) to formatDate() method will work on a local copy and would not interfere with each other. Which gives you thread safe behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But still one thing is not clear to me.     
<p>
public String formatDate(Date date) {  
      return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy").format(date);  
}
This would also have had the same effect. Returning new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy"); from initialValue() has the effect of creating new object for each thread. So how is ThreadLocal useful in this case. What is the correct use of it. ?

Comment: @nits.kk Did you find a satisfactory explanation? I still don't know what will be the difference between keeping a "private ThreadLocal<T>" and "private static Map<ThreadId, T>" in a class

Answer (score 1):

Thread-local storage serves the purpose of global variables within a context of a single thread.

Consider this example: you write a multithreaded program for processing user requests. Multiple users can initiate requests concurrently; your system uses one thread for each user.

When a user request arrives, your system figures out the user from which it came, and creates an instance of `UserPermissions` object for that user.

There are several ways to make that object available to your running program. One way is to pass `UserPermissions` to each method that may need it, and also to each method that calls, directly or indirectly, a method that may need it. This may be problematic, especially in contexts where callbacks are used.

Had your program not been multithreaded, you'd set `UserPermissions` in a global variable. Unfortunately, you cannot do that, because multiple user requests may be active at the same time.

This is where thread-local storage comes in: the process that creates the user permissions sets the `UserPermissions` object in thread-local storage, and leaves it there until the processing of the request is over. This way all methods can grab `UserPermissions` as needed, without having to pass them around as method parameters.

Comment: What is wrong with UserPermissions as a thread class data member/field?  This way all thread class methods can grab UserPermissions as needed, without having to pass them around as method parameters.

Comment: @MartinJames A big problem with this approach is the need to subclass a thread. The need to access user info "cuts across" multiple classes, some of them may be unrelated to the thread implementation class.

Answer (score 0):

You will use `ThreadLocal`to pass "data" to a *specific* thread.
For example you have a method `doSomething(SomeObject a, SomeOtherObject b);`
You can pass more information to this method for a **specific** thread of execution in a thread safe manner via thread locals than just `a` and `b`

Comment: Doesn't help.  Loading new data into thread-locals is no more or less thread-safe than loading new data into data fields of a thread class instance, ie. not thread safe and would need synchro, in general.

Comment: @MartinJames:No this is wrong.Threadlocal are unique and accessible to a specific thread.No synchronization needed

Comment: What data?Could you please provide a specific example?

Answer (score 0):

A thread local is a cheap way to implement [dynamic scoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Dynamic_scoping). With dynamic scoping, a binding  exists during the evaluation of a code block. In that case, the binding exists during the execution of a specific thread. Dynamic scoping was supported in early lisps, but it rarely makes sense, so most modern programming language do no support it, except via thread locals.

Dynamic scoping / thread locals are useful to maintain pervasive contextual information around, e.g.:

- security context
- log information (see [Nested Diagnostic Contexts](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html) in Log4j)
- current request

There's a line of research called "[context-oriented programming](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2008_03/article4/)" that aims at better supporting such concerns in programming languages. The paper "[context-oriented programming: beyond layers](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Loew07aPyContext.pdf)" shows some further examples.