# How threadlocal variable is different from a method level variable

Tags: java, thread-local

If I use a threadlocal variable, then each thread gets a local copy of the variable. My first question is, if each thread mutates the variable, will the mutated value stay in its local copy only? Or at some point will it try to update the 'global variable' too and we will run into concurrency issues?

My other question is: if I declare a variable in a method, then each thread executing the method in its own stack will get its own copy. So is declaring a method level variable the same as making it threadlocal?

Comment: Local variables are always thread safe. For `Thread Local Variable` check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817856/when-and-how-should-i-use-a-threadlocal-variable

Comment: What is the main feature of thread local?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question: each thread updates its copy of threadlocal variable, no global state is shared between threads.

Second question: if you declare local variable it behaves similary to threadlocal - every thread has its own copy but you don't have global access to it e.g. in another method - that's when threadlocal is useful.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to look at a `ThreadLocal<T>` object is as a `Map<Thread, T>`, where the `ThreadLocal#get()` call would lookup the proper value by calling `Map#get(Thread.currentThread())` on the underlying `Map`.  Note that this is not the actual implementation, but the easiest way to look at it.

`ThreadLocal` variables are only useful as a member that can actually be accessed by multiple threads at the same time.  Local declarations of a variable in a method are just that, local, and therefore not accessible to other threads.  I would not say they are 'the same', but that they are both threadsafe.

Typical usage would be an instance member variable of a singleton object, or a static member variable of a class, in a multi-threaded environment.

Mostly, you will see them used to pass around request context information in a servlet environment.

Answer (score 1):

> If i use a threadlocal variable, then each thread gets a local copy of
>   the variable

I think there is some cunfusion regarding the term *local copy of the variable*. There is no copy. Every thread gets its own variable; these are independant of each other. It doesn't mean, however, that they cannot hold a reference to a shared object. So, just using threadlocal variables alone does not save you from concurrency issues.

Regarding your second question: No. Local variables and threadlocal variables are different. Local variables are not accessible outside the block in which they are defined. Therefore, for example, calling the same method twice will result in a different value each time. On the other hand, threadlocal variables keep their values as long as the thread exists.

Basically, threadlocal variables are kind of 'static' variables for one single thread.

Answer (score 0):

An important point about ThreadLocal variable is the global access. It can be accessed from anywhere inside the thread.inside any method which calls in that thread context.

If you want to maintain a single instance of a variable for all instances of a class, you will use static-class member variables to do it. If you want to maintain an instance of a variable on a per-thread basis, you'll use thread-local variables. ThreadLocal variables are different from normal variables in that each thread has its own individually initialized instance of the variable, which it accesses via get() or set() methods.

Let's say you're developing a multithreaded code tracer whose goal is to uniquely identify each thread's path through your code. The challenge is that you need to coordinate multiple methods in multiple classes across multiple threads. Without ThreadLocal, this would be a complex problem. When a thread started executing, it would need to generate a unique token to identify it in the tracer and then pass that unique token to each method in the trace.

With ThreadLocal, things are simpler. The thread initializes the thread-local variable at the start of execution and then accesses it from each method in each class, with assurance that the variable will only host trace information for the currently executing thread. When it's done executing, the thread can pass its thread-specific trace to a management object responsible for maintaining all traces.

Using ThreadLocal makes sense when you need to store variable instances on a per-thread basis.