# Adding context information (firstname/lastname) during a JAX-RS (RestEasy) invocation

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jax-rs, cdi, resteasy

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
public class AuthInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor {...}
```

I have built the above interceptor, which:

1. Retrieves a user's id from a header field in HttpServletRequest.
2. Loads the User entity from the database using the user's ID.
3. Stores the user information (first name/dob/etc) from the entity in a @RequestScoped CDI bean.

The reason for this is to have the user's information available for all ongoing Session bean invocation (using the @Inject annotation).

This works, however there are cases (e.g. in @Asynchronous method calls) where CDI does not inject the @RequestScoped bean (a null reference is given instead).

I have also seen examples using

```
InvocationContext.getContextData().put("user-related-data-name", someObj)
```

however this doesn't appear to work, getting the user data after putting it in the map always returns a null pointer.

What is the best way to add this user information during the interceptor invocation so it is available throughout all subsequent request EJB invocations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds the same issue, here is a summary of my solution:

I wanted to see if there was a JavaEE way of doing this but instead I just stored the context information in thread local instead of a Request Scoped bean.

When I fork off a new thread, I have an interceptor which takes the current context information and stores it in the new thread local as well, hence the user's context info is available to both the original thread and the new one.

Note that there are also interceptors which clean up the values of thread local when they are no longer needed.

See here for a discussion on thread local: [When and how should I use a ThreadLocal variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817856/when-and-how-should-i-use-a-threadlocal-variable)