# @Autowired HttpServletRequest vs passing as parameter - best practice

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Assume we have defined a controller class which has `@Controller` annotation only.

Inside the class, we have defined `private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;` variable.

Spring Controllers are Singleton. When we defined `HttpServletRequest` as `@Autowired` in a web-application, will it be an issue?

I read from a web-site that even though it is `@Autowired` it just injects a proxy for the thread variable.

Is it true? In a multi-threaded environment can we use `@Autowired` or passing `HttpServletRequest` as a parameter to each method in the controller class would be the right approach?

Some websites says it is an issue and suggested to pass as a parameter whereas few say it will be an issue.

I don't understand which one is right.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Both are ok.
`@Autowired HttpServletRequest` and passing as a parameter are the same things.

Before passing `HttpServletRequest` to invocation method responding to `@RequestMapping` function, Spring stores the `HttpServletRequest` into a `ThreadLocal` type variable.

That `ThreadLocal` variable is a thread-safe map that keeps `HttpServletRequest` in the current thread context. The `@Autowired HttpServletRequest` proxy bean gets the correct request from that `ThreadLocal` variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the confirmation

Comment: Can you please update your answer with reference to documentation that supportings your `thread-safe` explanation?

Comment: @Raf, this can be confirmed too by looking at the source code beginning from `org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.RequestObjectFactory`.

Comment: Now I wonder how it could work at other Spring beans than Controller. Especially when it comes to asynch invocations as well as circuit-breaker (semaphore) kinds, that's not ThreadLocal involved. After I check the hierarchy, I've learned StandardServletAsyncWebRequest exists, but still not sure of the best practices/examples. Any references or docs, please share with us? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answering an old and accepted question here.

### comparison

**The `HttpServletRequest` is one of the supported controller method arguments** as specified in the [Spring Web MVC docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments)

The `@Autowired` way, on which I don't find much on the official sites from my searching results. But many SO answers mention that "Spring stores the HttpServletRequest into a ThreadLocal variable ... it would be injected per thread" based on inspecting the source code.

### some inspection I made

The assumption is reasonable, but where is the entry point? I tried printing the runtime class name of the autowired `HttpServletRequest` bean:

```java
// ... imports ...

@RestController
@Slf4j
public class K {
  @Autowired private HttpServletRequest request;

  @GetMapping public ResponseEntity<String> getIt() {
    log.info("GET request rt class is {}", request.getClass().getName());
    return ResponseEntity.ok("k");
  }
}
```

The output is something like `jdk.proxy2.$Proxy77`, right, it's a proxy injected. Then should use [`Proxy.getInvocationHandler(request).getClass().getName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344299/how-do-i-get-the-underlying-type-of-a-proxy-object-in-java). Now the output is `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AutowireUtils$ObjectFactoryDelegatingInvocationHandler`, a private nested class within [AutowireUtils](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/AutowireUtils.java), which has a field of type [`ObjectFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectFactory.html). The `ObjectFactory` has 16 implementations (you can use an IDE to check it out), the most likely one (**by assumption**) that gives the `ServletRequest` is the private nested class `RequestObjectFactory` within [`WebApplicationContextUtils`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.java):

```java
//...
private static ServletRequestAttributes currentRequestAttributes() {
    RequestAttributes requestAttr = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    if (!(requestAttr instanceof ServletRequestAttributes)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Current request is not a servlet request");
    }
    return (ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttr;
}

/**
 * Factory that exposes the current request object on demand.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
private static class RequestObjectFactory implements ObjectFactory<ServletRequest>, Serializable {
    @Override
    public ServletRequest getObject() {
        return currentRequestAttributes().getRequest();
    }
    // ...
}
// ...
```

As you can see, it comes to the [`RequestContextHolder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.java), a [Holder class to expose the web request in the form of a thread-bound `RequestAttributes` object](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html). Now it makes some sense.

---

See also

- [Spring: how do I inject an HttpServletRequest into a request-scoped bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320674/spring-how-do-i-inject-an-httpservletrequest-into-a-request-scoped-bean)
- [Is RequestContextHolder thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933224/is-requestcontextholder-thread-safe)