# Pass HttpHeaders in Open API Generator

Tags: java, spring, yaml, swagger, openapi

I have a requirement in which I need to pass entire HTTP header as argument in spring boot controller can this be done via open-api generator
My Controller is like

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/dummyUrl",
      produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
      consumes = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
  public ResponseEntity<DummyResponse>  processRequest(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers,@RequestBody UserDefineObject userDefineObject)
```

I Know how to process individual parameters in HttpHeaders by using

`parameters: -in:header`

inside my yaml file but how to obtain entire httpheader

Answer (score 0):

open API wont generate any header in controller but there are ways to get header using 2 methods

1.Using autowired HttpServletRequest variable ,this is managed by spring boot and is threadsafe, so any class which needs header information inject HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest.

2.The other way is [How to retrieve unspec'd headers with openapi-generator (spring)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61345599/how-to-retrieve-unspecd-headers-with-openapi-generator-spring)

Hope it helps any one who need it